# Project management with Git integration

Tags: git, project-management

I've looked around for a project management system, I've tried to use [this one](http://github.com/michaeldv/pit) but it lacks some features I want and doesn't really seem to be under any sort of active development.

I only need a few features:

1. Basic project/task management
2. Very good git integration (when I pull/push my repo I want the management files to go too)
3. Vim integration (or at least use the editor I have set a la 'export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim'
4. A note taking system (for meetings ideally)
5. Command line interface, there can be other interfaces too, but I really want CLI.

Of all the project management systems I've found, [fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/tip/www/quickstart.wiki) comes closest to satisfying my needs, but still falls short.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how [Fossil][1] falls short of your needs?  Maybe we can fix it...


  [1]: http://www.fossil-scm.org/

Comment: JIRA is one of the most popular http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview

Comment: Try RedCritterTracker, it's really cool https://www.redcrittertracker.com/home.aspx

Comment: Github have their own tool now: https://waffle.io

Comment: @Rimian can't see where it says that waffle.io is by GitHub? Or maybe I misunderstood your comment!

Comment: @Stormie I think you're right. I can't remember where I got that idea from. :)

Answer (score 4):

What about [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) or [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/)? They all cover your needs, except "Vim integration"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one of the Org-mode clones for VIM (e.g. [VimOrganizer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3342)) is the right tool for you:

1. It is designed for task managment
2. It uses only text files => git can track everything
3. It's integrated in VIM
4. Emacs Org-mode has a powerful note taking system (called [capture](http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html)). I don't know about the VIM clones. But at least you can write your notes directly into the plain text files.
5. There is no real CLI, but maybe VIM is all you want/need?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.springloops.com hands down atm, tested and demo'd pretty much everything over 2 days.

ps. Not an affiliate or anything Im just happy to have found them and this post comes up in Google search

Answer (score 2):

*Shameless self promotion warning*

[ScratchDocs](https://github.com/guyromm/ScratchDocs.git)!

- ScratchDocs uses Git to store its data, organized by folders and task files.
- Tasks are stored in org-mode.
- You have the notion of Iterations (think Scrum), Stories (top-level tasks) and Tasks, which are the same as stories but are used to break stories down.
- The whole thing has a cli interface written in Python.
- can be set up via a git hook to generate a through HTML export of the tasks after each push.
- Easily hackable and extendable to do whatever you fancy.

So, if you could use something like VimOrganizer for editing your task files, you'd be all set.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [CodebaseHQ](http://www.codebasehq.com/)? It's on online solution, but integrates project management with DVCSs other than Git.